# "Not like" neo4j regex

Tags: regex, neo4j

I want in Neo4j the equivalent of "not like" in SQL.

```
c.Education not like '%High%School%'
```

I have this:

```
 c.education =~ ".*High.*School.*"
```

But this works just "like" and I want the opposite.

Comment: Can you do `not(c.education =~ ".*High.*School.*")` ?

Comment: @nolan yes, I can :) Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To exclude the results of your regex condition, use

```
WHERE NOT ( condition )
```

See [*3.4.3.4.2. Filter on patterns using `NOT`*](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#where-filter-on-patterns-using-not):

> The `NOT` function can be used to exclude a pattern.

So, use

```
WHERE NOT (c.education =~ ".*High.*School.*")
```

Comment: If the answer proved helpful, also consider upvoting the answer  (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).